# Google Chrome errors while exporting XLS file using PHP

Tags: php, google-chrome

I've been using a PHP script to export data from my database (mysql) to a XLS file.

While the file export process is working fine on Firefox and IE.

I am getting errors when trying to export using Google Chrome.

The Google Chrome error is

```
    Duplicate headers received from server

The response from the server contained duplicate headers. This problem is generally the result of a misconfigured website or proxy. Only the website or proxy administrator can fix this issue.

Error 349 (net::ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION): Multiple distinct Content-Disposition headers received. This is disallowed to protect against HTTP response splitting attacks.
```

I need some assistance on this.

Thanks

Comment: There is something wrong with the HTTP response header. Catch the HTTP header using [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com) and post it here.

Comment: happened to me. fixed it by removing commas from the file name

Comment: another answer change `header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$file}");` to `header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$file}\"");`

Comment: In my case doing so caused the error described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530569/chrome-appends-hyphen-to-the-downloaded-csv-file

Answer (score 12):

I've found out what my problem was in the header section of the PHP export code. The incorrect and correct lines are as follows:

Incorrect

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=\"".$this->filename."\"");
```

Correct

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$this->filename."\"");
```

The correction being adding a space between **attachment;** and **filename**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 9):

I had this same problem. However appearing only very rarely. Cause was similar but not quite the same.

Incorrect

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
```

Correct

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
```

$filename sometimes contained spaces resulting in mentionec Chrome error.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same problem. While downloading a file having comma in its name it was saying "**duplicate headers received**" and it is only in chrome. In Firefox it was OK. After that I just changed my code from 
`header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$myfilename");` to
`header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$myfilename\"");` and it worked fine. Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Thanks, I have 2700 pages and it works in Chrome for about 96% but not the other 4% but it does work in Edge 100% of the time.

Answer (score 2):

Try this may help you,
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=**"'.$file_name.'"'**);

instead of

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$file_name);