# PHPExcel file cannot open file because the file format or file extension is not valid

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm stuck with this problem, it's not displaying the actual excel file. Please check my code below:

```
/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/** PHPExcel */
require_once 'PHPExcel.php';
include 'PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php';


// Create new PHPExcel object
#echo date('H:i:s') . " Create new PHPExcel object\n";
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$excel = new PHPExcel();

$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle("Payroll");

if(!$result){
die("Error");
}
$col = 0; 
$row = 2; 
while($mrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
$col = 0; 
foreach($mrow as $key=>$value) { 
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $value); 
    $col++; 
} 
$row++;  
} 

 // Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
 $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A1', 'Scholar Id')
        ->setCellValue('B1', 'Lastname')
        ->setCellValue('C1', 'Middlename')
        ->setCellValue('D1', 'Firstname')
        ->setCellValue('E1', 'Barangay')
        ->setCellValue('F1', 'Level')
        ->setCellValue('G1', 'Allowance')
        ->setCellValue('H1', 'Has claimed?');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:H1')->getFont()->setBold(true);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(12);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(18);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setWidth(18);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('D')->setWidth(18);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('E')->setWidth(18);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('F')->setWidth(12);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('G')->setWidth(12);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('H')->setWidth(14);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:H1')->getAlignment()- >setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setShowGridlines(true);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:H1')->applyFromArray(
array(
    'fill' => array(
        'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
        'color' => array('rgb' => 'FFFF00')
    )
)
); 


// Save Excel 2007 file
echo date('H:i:s') . " Write to Excel2007 format\n";
#$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="payroll.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); 
$writer->save('php://output');
```

Comment: Whenever you see this error, the first thing you should do is open the file in a text editor and look for whitespace characters (space, tab, newlines, etc) at the beginning or end of file, or a BOM marker, or any obvious PHP human-readable error messages in the content of the file

Comment: @MarkBaker when I opened the file it contains no codes or anything

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I got it working now! Thanks to this [phpexcel to download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566196/phpexcel-to-download)

I changed the code to this:

```
// Save Excel 2007 file
#echo date('H:i:s') . " Write to Excel2007 format\n";
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
ob_end_clean();
// We'll be outputting an excel file
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="payroll.xlsx"');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

I think this line:

```
ob_end_clean();
```

solved my problem.

Comment: if ob_end_clean() solved the problem, then it means something in your code was generating output... best fix to find out what, and remove it.... viewing the generated file in a text editor should have given a clue as to what output was being generated

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes. Yes. Certainly it (ob_end_clean) did solved my problem. Thank you!

Comment: This worked for me too, I was having an error of invalid format error message and when i put this code, it worked for me as well. Thank you!

Comment: Not working for me on php 7.4

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if i can help i had the same problem and i solved with

```
ob_end_clean();
```

i put it just after

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
```

So don't change the header and save it as xslx anyway, the problem is the buffer!

Answer (score 2):

The most likely culprit if this is a cut-and-paste of your script is the

```
echo date('H:i:s') . " Write to Excel2007 format\n";
```

If you're sending to the browser for download, then there must be no other output (echoes, print statements, dropping in and out of PHP) than the output generated to php://output by PHPExcel itself

Comment: I commented out the echo date('H:i:s') . " Write to Excel2007 format\n"; but it still is not displaying the excel file? But the excel file is saved in my php excel folder. I want the user to choose where he/she wants to save it? How can I do that?

Comment: The browser should be directed to offer the download dialogue by the headers that you send.... but I'm confused by your question and coomments. The question suggested that you were getting the download dialogue, but the file was corrupted. Now you're saying that you don't get the download dialogue

Comment: Yes I myself am confused. Sorry, but right now my problem is the browser is download the excel.php itself, the excel file is downloaded as well in my folder, but I want the user to choose where he should save it.

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure that all files (e.g. that are included) are in UTF-8 **without BOM** encoding.
You can identify this in different ways, e.g. see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204765/elegant-way-to-search-for-utf-8-files-with-bom).

Only if you need UTF-8 **with BOM** - please use `ob_end_clean();` before data outputing to browser, as pointed in other answers here.

Answer (score 1):

This answer save my life. Thanks @ARN

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, "Excel2007");
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export_result.xlsx"');
for ($i = 0; $i < ob_get_level(); $i++) {
   ob_end_flush();
}
ob_implicit_flush(1);
ob_clean();
$objWriter->save("php://output");
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, the problem is simple. Just put code below :

```
ob_end_clean();
```

after :

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the solution of this problem is the same as here:
[Google Chrome errors while exporting XLS file using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782050/google-chrome-errors-while-exporting-xls-file-using-php)

just add a space between **attachement;** and **filename**, that way :

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"Past_Due_Report.xls\"");
```

as i can see in your own answer that's what you did, and is probably what fixed your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but calling `ob_end_clean()` didn't work. My CMS (drupal 7) had messed up my headers so I got a new line (hex `0A`) at the beginning of the content even if I called `ob_end_clean()` before the file output.

With the code below I finaly got rid of the leading new line:

```
 for ($i = 0; $i < ob_get_level(); $i++) { ob_end_flush(); }
      ob_implicit_flush(1);

 ob_clean();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but i using library [phpspreadsheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/)

just put this function:

```
ob_end_clean();
```

after  this code :

```
$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
```