# PHP Excel API Error: File Format or File Extension not valid

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I am experiencing an error on my code "File Format or File Extension not valid". I am using the PHP Excel class

This is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
ini_set('max_execution_time', 1200); //20 mins
ob_start();

/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);

 /** Include path **/
ini_set('include_path', ini_get('include_path').';../classes/');

/** PHPExcel */
include '../classes/PHPExcel.php';

/** PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007 */
include '../classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php';

// Create new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();


require_once '../classes/PHPExcel.php';


ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
    //Untested... pulled from the manual as the way to write with PHPExcel
    //Save Excel 2007 file
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    ob_end_clean();
    //We'll be outputting an excel file
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
    //It will be called file.xls
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=\"Past_Due_Report.xls\"");
    header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
    exit();
?>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: instead of opening the file save it and look at it in a text editor

Comment: I think when we are using PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007') i.e. "Excel2007" then the file extension will be .xlsx... so you have tho change the "Past_Due_Report.xls" to "Past_Due_Report.xlsx"

Comment: @pAsh i already changed to .xlsx, same error

Comment: remove '\'  before & after the -> Past_Due_Report.xlsx

Comment: @pAsh already removed '\' still getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

i think the solution of this problem is the same as here:
[Google Chrome errors while exporting XLS file using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782050/google-chrome-errors-while-exporting-xls-file-using-php)

just add a space between **attachement;** and **filename**, that way :

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"Past_Due_Report.xls\"");
```

Answer (score -1):

Below code works from my side..
In your code you create object 1st "PHPExcel" then include the file.. i do some needful changes. check link : https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

```
session_start();
ini_set('max_execution_time', 1200); //20 mins
ob_start();
/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
 /** Include path **/
ini_set('include_path', ini_get('include_path').';../classes/');

/** PHPExcel */
/*include '../classes/PHPExcel.php';*/

/** PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007 */
/*include '../classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php';*/

require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../Classes/PHPExcel.php';
// Create new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
    //Untested... pulled from the manual as the way to write with PHPExcel
    //Save Excel 2007 file
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    ob_end_clean();
    //We'll be outputting an excel file
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
    //It will be called file.xls
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=\"Past_Due_Report.xls\"");
    header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
    exit();
```